# Animate the slider, using another buttons from out side of the slider

Tags: jquery

i need to click this slider by out side buttons (div class).

[slider](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/DraggableImageBoxesGrid/)

in this slider, when click on image,it is maximize image and we can slide it using left and right arrows.

i need to trigger this left and right button, from out side of the slider, using another next and right button.

can any one help with this

is there Any other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way I can think without messing with the plugin is using jquery's [.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger)

```
$("#YOUR_PREVIOUS_BUTTON").click(function (e) {
    $(".ib-nav-prev").trigger("click");
});

$("#YOUR_NEXT_BUTTON").click(function (e) {
    $(".ib-nav-next").trigger("click");
});
```

This will trigger the click event on the buttons within the slider.

Comment: i tried this way , but its not working. is there Any other solutions.